# how to store / insert / format number in text column in oracle?

Tags: oracle, numbers, string-formatting, number-formatting

I'm new in Oracle and I have this problem. I have two tables Tab1 and Tab2. In Tab1 I have column Tab1Col1 of VARCHAR2(50 BYTE), in Tab2 I have column Tab2Col1 of NVARCHAR2(50 CHAR). I try to copy data from Tab1Col1 into Tab2Col1 using this query:

```
insert into Tab2(Tab2Col1)
select Tab1Col1
from Tab1
where [condition];
```

And I get really weird results, like these:

```
Tab1Col1 | Tab2Col1
18900    | 1,89E+004                                          
18900    | 1,89E+004                                          
16240    | 1,624E+004                                         
16240    | 16240
```

I mean weird because of sometimes the value is copied as it is and sometimes it is formatted (thats something what I do not want to). Could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

I have one more related question. Is there some way how to correctly read numbers (if it is) from text column (Tab2Col1) while they are in different formats (1,624E+004, 16240)?

Thanks,
Pavel

Comment: Which database version are you using?

Comment: It is 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit.

Comment: I've been trying to populate the same error on my machine with 10G release but it returns correct result. 
Not much difference on SQL Fiddle either. 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d179e/1

Comment: You might want to check your nls settings on the client - select * from nls_session_parameters. Also you can check that you have a valid number using to_number() function in the select or use to_char to format a number as a character (with format mask). It's probably a bad idea to be storing numbers in a varchar column anyway